# Why is equals() not called while adding to HashSet and hashCode matches?

Tags: java

When I run this code why only `hashCode()` is called not `equals` method while my `hashCode()` implementation generate same `hashCode` for both entries to `HashSet`?

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st=new Student(89);
        HashSet st1=new HashSet();
        st1.add(st);
        st1.add(st);
        System.out.println("Ho size="+st1.size());
    }
}
class Student{
    private int name;
    private int ID;
    public Student(int iD) {
        super();
        this.ID = iD;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("Hello-hashcode");
        return ID;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Hello-equals");
        if(obj instanceof Student){
            if(this.ID==((Student)obj).ID){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;  
    }
}
```

The output for this is:

```
Hello-hashcode
Hello-hashcode
Ho size=1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [hashcode() and equals() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919464/hashcode-and-equals-method)

Comment: Are you *purposefully* not overriding the hashCode() method?

Comment: @Vishrant - this is not duplicate - the part "why `equals` may not be  called" is not covered in the linked question.

Comment: san9w, I've edited title - see if you are ok/revert/improve.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The hash set checks reference equality first, and if that passes, it skips the `.equals` call. This is an optimization and works because the contract of `equals` specifies that if `a == b` then `a.equals(b)`.

I attached the source code below, with this check highlighted.

If you instead add two equal elements that are not the same reference, you get the effect you were expecting:

```
    HashSet st1=new HashSet();
    st1.add(new Student(89));
    st1.add(new Student(89));
    System.out.println("Ho size="+st1.size());
```

results in

```
$ java Test1
Hello-hashcode
Hello-hashcode
Hello-equals
Ho size=1
```

---

Here's the source code from OpenJDK 7, with equality optimization indicated (from HashMap, the underlying implementation of HashSet):

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
//                                         v-- HERE
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: ^ this.  I commented below with the same thing, but I guess we were submitting at the same time.  I didn't think giving a full code explanation was necessary.  It would just be silly to do a logical equality check if the object reference (the reference is pointing to the same memory) is the same.

Answer (score 9):

A `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` as its backing mechanism for the set.  Normally, we would expect that `hashCode` and `equals` would be called to ensure that there are no duplicates.  However, the `put` method (which calls a `private` `putVal` method to do the actual operation) makes an optimization in the source code:

```
if (e.hash == hash &&
    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
```

If the hash codes match, it first checks to see if the keys are the same before calling `equals`.  You are passing the same `Student` object, so they are already `==`, so the `||` operator short-circuits, and `equals` is never called.

If you passed in a different `Student` object but with the same `ID`, then `==` would return `false` and `equals` would be called.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the source code of `HashSet` it is using `HashMap` for all of its operations and the add method performs `put(element, SOME_CONSTANT_OBJECT)`. Here is the source code for the put method for JDK 1.6.0_17 :

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

as you can see it performs a `==` comparison before using the equals method. Since you are adding the same instance of an object twice the `==` returns true and the equals method is never called.

Answer (score 3):

> Equals is always called after the hashCode method in a java hashed
>   collection while adding and removing elements. The reason being, if
>   there is an element already at the specified bucket, then JVM checks
>   whether it is the same element which it is trying to put.

[hashcode() and equals() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919464/hashcode-and-equals-method)

Comment: Is the java api incorrect then? From 'add': "...adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). "

Comment: ? 'Hello equals' doesn't get called in the OP's code. for this to be an answer shouldn't this explain why?

Comment: You're not calling .equals, because the reference checks dictate that the object reference is the same, so there's no need to run logical equality checks.

Answer (score 3):

If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.